# bower degrades chart.js each time installing other packages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, bower, chart.js

Each time I want to install a package using bower, the **chart.js** packages also gets updated and degrades itself to version 1.1.1 and all of the files inside the chart.js directory gets deleted except

```
.bower.json 
bower.json 
Chart.js
```

whereas I need the other files, css files in particular.

Here is the example of what i do on my terminal:

```
C:\Users\Martin\Work\MyApp>bower install --save angular-chart.js
bower cached        https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js.git#1.1.1
bower validate      1.1.1 against https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js.git#*
bower cached        https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js.git#2.5.0
bower validate      2.5.0 against https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js.git#^2.5.0
bower cached        https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js.git#2.5.0
bower validate      2.5.0 against https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js.git#2.x
bower install       chart.js#2.5.0

chart.js#2.5.0 bower_components\chart.js

C:\Users\Martin\Work\MyApp>bower install --save datatables.net
bower cached        https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js.git#1.1.1
bower validate      1.1.1 against https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js.git#^1.0.0-beta
bower cached        https://github.com/DataTables/Dist-DataTables.git#1.10.15
bower validate      1.10.15 against https://github.com/DataTables/Dist-DataTables.git#*
bower cached        https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js.git#1.1.1
bower validate      1.1.1 against https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js.git#^1.1.0
bower cached        https://github.com/DataTables/Dist-DataTables.git#1.10.15
bower validate      1.10.15 against https://github.com/DataTables/Dist-DataTables.git#>=1.10.
9
bower install       angular-chart.js#1.1.1
bower install       Chart.js#1.1.1

angular-chart.js#1.1.1 bower_components\angular-chart.js
├── angular#1.5.10
└── chart.js#2.5.0

Chart.js#1.1.1 bower_components\Chart.js
```

for example, I installed angular-chart.js and automatically it updated and installed chart.js to version **2.5**, which is fine. 
But later when I install another package like **datatables.net**, as you see, the chart.js gets downgraded to version **1.1**

here is my bower.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.3",
    "fastclick": "~1.0.6",
    "angular": "~1.5.7",
    "angular-animate": "~1.5.7",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.5.7",
    "angular-resource": "~1.5.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.5.7",
    "angular-touch": "~1.5.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "ngstorage": "~0.3.10",
    "angular-translate": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-url": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "~2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "~2.7.2",
    "oclazyload": "~0.6.3",
    "angular-breadcrumb": "~0.4.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~1.3.3",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.7.1",
    "angular-scroll": "~0.6.5",
    "angular-moment": "~1.0.0",
    "AngularJS-Toaster": "~0.4.10",
    "angular-bootstrap-nav-tree": "*",
    "angular-ladda": "~0.3.1",
    "ng-table": "~0.8.3",
    "angular-ui-select": "~0.18.0",
    "angular-ui-utils": "mask-0.2.2",
    "ngImgCrop": "~0.3.2",
    "angular-file-upload": "~1.1.5",
    "angular-aside": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-truncate": "*",
    "angular-sweetalert-promised": "~1.0.4",
    "angular-elastic": "~2.4.2",
    "tc-angular-chartjs": "~1.0.9",
    "angular-ui-switch": "~0.1.1",
    "angular-ckeditor": "~1.0.3",
    "angular-bootstrap-calendar": "~0.18.2",
    "angular-xeditable": "~0.1.9",
    "checklist-model": "~0.2.4",
    "ng-nestable": "~0.0.1",
    "ng-flow": "~2.7.1",
    "v-accordion": "~1.2.7",
    "angular-notification-icons": "~0.4.2",
    "angular-spectrum-colorpicker": "~1.4.1",
    "components-modernizr": "~2.8.3",
    "moment": "~2.8.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "0.6.1",
    "ladda": "~0.9.8",
    "sweetalert": "~0.4.2",
    "jquery.sparkline.build": "~2.1.3",
    "ckeditor": "~4.5.6",
    "nestable": "*",
    "spin.js": "~2.0.2",
    "bootstrap-touchspin": "~3.0.1",
    "select2": "~4.0.0",
    "select2-bootstrap-css": "~1.4.6",
    "selectize": "~0.12.0",
    "animate.css": "~3.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "themify-icons": "0.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
    "bootstrap-rtl": "~3.3.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.3",
    "angular-strap": "^2.3.9",
    "ng-tags-input": "^3.1.1",
    "angulartics-google-analytics": "^0.3.0",
    "angulartics": "^1.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "angular-chart.js": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^2.1.0",
    "cryptojslib": "^3.1.2",
    "datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.3.2",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.2",
    "pivottable": "^2.3.0",
    "c3": "^0.4.11",
    "d3": "^4.4.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.3",
    "angular-modal-service": "^0.10.1",
    "angularjs-slider": "^5.9.0",
    "seiyria-bootstrap-slider": "^9.5.4",
    "html2canvas": "^0.4.1",
    "angular-recaptcha": "^4.0.1",
    "js-base64": "^2.1.9",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15"
  },
  "ignoredDependencies": [
    "chart.js"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

i tried to put **chart.js** in the ignored dependencies list, but no good.

Please help me understand why this is happening, and help me solve this.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly tell `bower` to install specific version of a dependency using the [`resolutions`](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#resolutions) attribute.

Like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
}, 
...
"resolutions": {
  "chart.js": "2.5.0"
}
```

Comment: I did as you told, and tried to run bower `install --save angular-chart.js` twice. Supposing that the first time, my chart.js folder is faulty, and at version 1.1.1, so it reinstalls it and corrects it, but then if i re-run it, it downgrades back to 1.1.1, and if i rerun it again, it goes back to 2.5.0. What is this spectacle for?

Comment: @passion that's weird. maybe you can remove all the dependencies related to chart.js including itself and then install them